# Restore UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, state-restoration

I've assigned restorationIdentifier to subclass of UICollectionViewCell
When app moves to background `encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` got called, but when app restores `decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder)` is not called.

I've tried to assign restorationIdentifier to UICollectionView but it doesn't help too.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Why would you need to restore the cell?  Restore the data that feeds your collection view and the cells will be requested from the data source as usual.

Comment: I have a cell with textView for user input, and need to restore text from it.